# Undefined join condition between parent/child tables

Tags: join, orm, foreign-key-relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's a model for a basic todo app, in which a user can create a tasklist that contains tasks:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from allot import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)

    tasklists = db.relationship('Tasklist', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username

class Tasklist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))

    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='tasklist', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, title, description, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.user_id = user_id

class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title= db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
    tasklist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Tasklist.id'))

    def __init__ (self, title, status, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.tasklist_id = tasklist_id
```

It generates this error:

> ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child
>   tables on relationship User.tasklists.  Specify a 'primaryjoin'
>   expression.  If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as
>   well.

Adding `primaryjoin` arguments in the relationships, like this:

```
tasklists = db.relationship('Tasklist', backref='user', primaryjoin='user.id==Tasklist.user_id', lazy='dynamic')
```

... returns:

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't
>   proceed with initialization of other mappers.

What's wrong with the model?

I searched for an explanation in the [relationship][1] doc and on SO but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that when you're referencing foreign keys your using the uppercase "User" when you actually need to use the lowercase **tablename** reference. Try this:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from allot import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)

    tasklists = db.relationship('Tasklist', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='user', lazy='joined'))

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username

class Tasklist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasklist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='tasklist', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, title, description, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.user_id = user_id

class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title= db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    tasklist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasklist.id'))

    def __init__ (self, title, status, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.tasklist_id = tasklist_id
```